# Перебор всех возможных комбинаций нулей и единиц

Tags: javascript

У меня имеется массив arr, состоящий из нулей и единиц. Например `arr = [0,0,1,1,1]` Как мне перебрать всевозможные комбинации, при котором число единиц и нулей остается постоянным (по примеру кол-во нулей = 2, а кол-во единиц = 3)? Всего их C(5,3) или же C(5,2), где C = n!/( (n-k)!*k!) ).

Comment: Все возможные комбинации элементов массива.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К комбинаторике моё решение не относится и можете его даже не рассматривать. Просто глядя на нули и единицы, такой вариант родился сам собой, вот и решил поделиться ;)

```js
const bindec = (bin) => {
    return parseInt((bin + '').replace(/[^01]/g, ''), 2)
};

const decbin = (dec, len) => {
    let out = '';
    while (len--)
        out += (dec >> len) & 1;
    return out;
};
const add = (a, b) => +a + +b;

const permutation = (arr) => {
    arr = arr.sort();
    let len = arr.length,
        from = bindec(arr),
        to = bindec(arr.reverse()),
        out = [];
    for (; from <= to; from++) {
        out.push(decbin(from, len).split(''));
    }
    const sum = arr.reduce(add);
    return out.filter(a => a.reduce(add) === sum);
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(permutation([0, 0, 1, 1, 1])));
```

Comment: А есть ли более эффективный и нерекурсивный способ решения?

Answer (score 0):

Вариант ...

```js
function fn(e, f) {
  for (var b = [], a = [], d = e; d--;) {
    a.push([d]), b.forEach(function(c) {
      c.length < f && -1 == c.indexOf(d) && a.push(c.slice(0).concat(d));
    }), b = b.concat(a), a = [];
  }
  return b.filter(function(c) {
    return c.length == f;
  }).map(function(c) {
    for (var b = [], a = 0; a < e; a++) {
      b.push(+!!~c.indexOf(a));
    }
    return b;
  });
};
document.write(JSON.stringify(fn(5, 3)))
```